# ajax MouseOver and MouseOut script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Currently this will load the div id call "tasksOnThisDay" with this MouseOver script. But my end point objective is to close this div when I MouseOut. Or is there a better way of writing the script so that I can pass a GET parameter over to my Task.html and then load it on the div, additional to the MouseOver and MouseOut script? Can somebody help me take a look, thanks in advance!

```
<span class="label label-warning" style="background:'#fff'" 
target="_blank" onmouseover="
$(\'#tasksOnThisDay .modal-body\').load(\'Task.html?day='.$date.'\',
function(e){$(\'#tasksOnThisDay\').modal(\'show\');
});
">'$date'</span>
```

Comment: Use jQuery event binding instead of javascript attributes. That'll make you have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a go. You'll have to include the following javascript which you can download:
https://jquery.com/download/

```
  <span class="label label-warning" style="background:'#fff'" 
         target="_blank">'$date'</span>


        <script>
        // using jquery function $(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction)
$(".label label-warning").hover(function(){
        // When hover over
      $(this).load('Task.html?day='.$date.'\', function()
    {
        $(\'#tasksOnThisDay\').toggle()});
    },
    function(){


         //  When mouse is not hovering
        $(this).empty();
        $(\'#tasksOnThisDay\').toggle();

});
```